# Has anyone used Bitstamp international bank transfer?

Tags: withdrawal, wire-transfers, bitstamp

I want to use bitstamp to sell my bitcoins and receive USD in my bank account in Pakistan through wire transfer. Has anyone used this service at bitstamp? How long does it normally take and did you experience any hurdles in the process?
Also are there any alternative services like bitstamp which are reliable, offer good conversion rates and low fees for international transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used it, and it worked fine. You could also check out telenor, I think they are selling bitcoins in Pakistan, so no need to trade abroad. The premium may be worth paying given the rising value of the coins i.e your $ buying power may diminish whilst your transfer is processed by the banks.

Comment: Thanks! How long did bitstamp take to process the wire transfer?

Comment: nabeel, the transfer took around 3 days. It all depends on how quickly you can provide them your personal details.